# Microsoft Excel - How to query a SQL Server with parameters based on cell value, then place the result set in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Ideally there would be a button you press within excel. When the user presses this button it sends a query to the SQL Server database and places the results of that query into excel. There would be a specific cell where the user enters a date, this date is used in the query.

I am not sure the best method to use to connect to the SQL Server in order to achieve this. It needs to be a query which has parameters based on cell values.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not only that, you would have to ensure that the user didn't enter "fred" as his date, and that macros are enabled.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/294779/pass-a-cell-contents-as-a-parameter-to-an-excel-query-in-excel-2007

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with VBA, but if you want to do something similar without coding, you can go to the "Data" tab on the ribbon, select "From Other Sources" on the "Get External Data" section, and follow the prompts to make a linked table on a sheet. This should work assuming you don't run into data limits. Then you can use excel formulas on another sheet to manipulate the data in a way that approximates a query.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find a solution by going to the "Data" tab, and then selecting  "From Other Sources" -> "From Microsoft Query". It is a somewhat annoying way to do it, and it gives you lots of hardships if your query cannot be represented in a view, but there are ways to work around it. This is a great guide for anyone trying to do this: http://superuser.com/questions/197453/run-an-sql-query-with-a-parameter-from-excel-2007